# use foreign key constraint to ensure valid data entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have been cleaning up a database table which was bit of a nightmare.

I want to ensure that the data being entered going forward is correct. So I read about foreign key constraints.

So below is a table where the data gets entered into.

**tblSales**

```
  Country      Seller       Value
  52           01           100
  86           01           100
  102          32           100
  32           52           100
  52           01           100
```

I want to ensure the values being entered into the Country & Seller fields are a certain set of values. There is also a table called tblMap which is used for reports to give the numbers a name which is easy to read.

**tblMap**

```
Factor      Code      Name      
Country     52        US
Country     86        Germany
Country     102       Spain
Country     32        Italy
Seller      01        Bob
Seller      32        Sarah
Seller      52        Jim
```

So like I say I was going to use a foreign key constraint but I can't create a primary key on the Code field in tblMap as 52 is used for both a country and a seller. I am not able to change the code numbers either.

Am I still able to use a foreign key constrain to ensure any value entered into tblSales exists in tblMap?

Comment: Best dealt with by splitting `tblMap`. This is such a well-known anti-pattern that it even has a name - the One True Lookup Table (OTLT). You can search for various articles on why its a bad idea. Complexity of foreign key enforcement is one of the first that appears in most articles.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can replace `tblMap` by 2 tables `tblMapCountry` and `tblMapSeller`

**tblMapCountry**

```
Code      Name      
52        US
86        Germany
102       Spain
32        Italy
```

**tblMapSeller**

```
Code      Name      
01        Bob
32        Sarah
52        Jim
```

After you can base

- a FK between tblSales.country and tblMapCountry
- a FK between tblSales.seller and tblMapSeller

At the end you can build a view `tblMap` by union the 2 tables `tblMapCountry` and `tblMapSeller`

```
create view `tblMap`
as
select 'Country' as Factor,Code,Name from tblMapCountry
union all
select 'Seller' as Factor,Code,Name from tblMapSeller
```